# find the least value of x+y given the following conditions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If the eight digit number $5668x25y$  is divisible by $48$ find the least value of x+y

**MyApproach:**

$5668x25y$ is divisible by $48$.I took prime factors of 48=$2^4$ . $3$

So,I thought: $5$+$6$+$6$+$8$+$1$+$2$+$5$+$0$=33

Least Value must be x+y=$1$+$0$=$1$

But,the options given are A)$10$ B)$9$ C)$7$ D)$8$

> Can Anyone guide how to approach the problem?

Comment: Your number, $56681250$ is not divisible by $16$, nor even by $4$.

Comment: Are options B and C supposed to be the same?

Comment: i think one of the option should be 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right that the sum of all the digits should be a multiple of $3$--this is both necessary and sufficient for this integer to be divisible by $3$--consequently, $x+y$ must be of the form $3k+1$ for some integer $k$. As $x$ and $y$ are digits, the only possibilites for $x+y$ are: $1,4,7,10,13,$ and $16$.

However, you must also ensure that the number is divisible by $2^4.$ Since $56680000$ is divisible by $2^4,$ then you need only ensure that $x25y$ is divisible by $2^4.$ Note that $y$ is necessarily even, which will cut down on the number of options.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: To be divisible by $48$, the number must be divisible by $8$.  For this to occur, the last three digits considered as a single number (in the hundreds) must be divisible by $8$.  The only number between $250$ and $259$ divisible by $8$ is $256$.

This gives you the last digit.  Try to go on from there.

Comment: +1: Nice observation! Much simpler than trying to make it divisible by $16$ all at once.

Comment: This implies the number can also be divisible by $16$.y can be $6$ and x can be $1$.

Comment: Nice observation.

Answer (score 0):

A number divisible by 48 should also be divisible by 8 and 6 since 8.6=48 so last digit of your number should be 6 as for a number to be divisible by 8 last three digits need to be divisible by eight . for a number to be divisible by 6 it should be divisible by 2 and 3 it is already divisible by 2 as last digit here as we found is 6 now for a number to be divisible by 3 the addition of all digits should be an integral multiple of 3 so we add all we get 38+x the nearest value to 38 which is divisible by 3 is 39 so x=1 . Hence x=1 and y=6 so x+y=7 which is its  minimum value .